# How to implement user based permissions on certain applications?

Tags: node.js, express

I currently have a rest api implemented with nodejs and express.

There is a single login endpoint for users to authenticate with and I am using JWT to authorize requests.

The API has multiple 'apps' within the api, for example a 'returns app' which is for users to handle customer returns.

I want to assign a role and and several apps to each user, so that a user may be able to access the 'returns app' and 'reviews app' and perform actions but not be authorized to the 'purchase app'

I currently have some middleware that will identify the user and attach it to the request:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

    // verify user with JWT
    req.user = JWT;
    next();

}
```

how can I implement role based permission per application?

I want to be able to assign a user multiple apps and roles something along these lines:

```
user1: {
    "role": "editor"
    "apps": ["returns", "reviews"]
}
```

Is there a good way to implement this type of functionality?

EDIT:

If the JWT contains:

```
const user = {
    name: John,
    role: "editor",
    apps: ["returns", "reviews"]
}
```

How should I parse the JWT with middleware to determine the users authorization. e.g. an 'editor' role has the

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the permissions in the jwt payload when you create it.

```
const payload = {
    role: "editor",
    apps: ["returns", "reviews"]
}

jwt.sign(payload, jwtSecret)
```

And give access to the different apps based on the permissions contained in the jwt you receive.

Edit:

The middleware handling the permissions could look like this:

```
function reviewsPermissions(req, res, next) {
    const token = jwt.decode(req.headers.authorization)

    if (token.apps.includes('reviews') && token.role === 'editor')
        next()
    else 
        res.status(401).json({ error: "Access restricted to editors."})
}

router.post('/reviews', reviewsPermissions, (req, res) => {
    // Your code
})
```

Comment: That is what I am trying to achieve, I am just unsure how to best implement the middleware efficiently to parse the roles and app combinations.